# Converting str to dict in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, rrdtool

I got this from a process's output using subprocess.Popen() :

```
    { about: 'RRDtool xport JSON output',
  meta: {
    start: 1401778440,
    step: 60,
    end: 1401778440,
    legend: [
      'rta_MIN',
      'rta_MAX',
      'rta_AVERAGE'
          ]
     },
  data: [
    [ null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null  ]
  ]
}
```

It doesn't seem to be a valid json to me.
I have used `ast.literal_eval()` and `json.loads()`, but with no luck.
Can someone help me in the right direction ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't get the process to produce strict JSON, try a [more relaxed parser](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/).

Comment: This is indeed not valid JSON; the key names need quoting. Is the JSON formatted with this much whitespace, always?

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Yes, the key names should be in quotes indeed.I am not sure about the number of whitespaces, as well.

Comment: @Shark: We can either try to repair the JSON, or you'll have to use `demjson` to load this.

Comment: @Shark: I'm asking about whitespace because you could have re-formatted the JSON to work in a post here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No I haven't re-formatted the json, I just copy-pasted the output from subprocess.Popen().communicate()

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Do I really need to use demjson here ? Isn't there a way to repair the above json ?

Comment: Just double quot the keys and the string values.

Comment: @Shark: there is, but with caveats.

Comment: @salmanwahed: the problem is doing that in an automated fashion that won't further break the JSON format.

Comment: OP wanted a direction. Not code I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, older versions of `rddtool` export ECMA-script, not JSON. According to [this debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=686825) upgrading 1.4.8 should give you proper JSON. Also see the project [CHANGELOG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/pub/CHANGES):

> JSON output of xport is now actually json compilant by its keys
>     being properly quoted now.

If you cannot upgrade, you have two options here; either attempt to reformat to apply quoting the object key identifiers, or use a parser that's more lenient and parses ECMA-script object notation.

The latter can be done with the external [`demjson` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/demjson):

```
>>> import demjson
>>> demjson.decode('''\
... { about: 'RRDtool xport JSON output',
...   meta: {
...     start: 1401778440,
...     step: 60,
...     end: 1401778440,
...     legend: [
...       'rta_MIN',
...       'rta_MAX',
...       'rta_AVERAGE'
...           ]
...      },
...   data: [
...     [ null, null, null ],
...     [ null, null, null ],
...     [ null, null, null ],
...     [ null, null, null ],
...     [ null, null, null ],
...     [ null, null, null  ]
...   ]
... }''')
{u'about': u'RRDtool xport JSON output', u'meta': {u'start': 1401778440, u'step': 60, u'end': 1401778440, u'legend': [u'rta_MIN', u'rta_MAX', u'rta_AVERAGE']}, u'data': [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]}
```

Repairing can be done using a regular expression; I am going to assume that all identifiers are on a new line or directly after the opening `{` curly brace. Single quotes in the list will have to be changed to double quotes; this will only work if there are no embedded single quotes in the values too:

```
import re
import json

yourtext = re.sub(r'(?:^|(?<={))\s*(\w+)(?=:)', r' "\1"', yourtext, flags=re.M)
yourtext = re.sub(r"'", r'"', yourtext)
data = json.loads(yourtext)
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of using `demjson` over `yaml` ? Bcz both are giving me proper result.

Comment: @Shark: YAML claims to be a superset of JSON, where this syntax happens to work for YAML too. demjson explicitly allows for the syntax used here as it sees this as ECMAScript. It could be there is *some* syntax that RDDTool produces that either tool doesn't parse, but my gut instinct is to use demjson here.

Comment: @Shark One possible advantage is that your output explicitly claims to be JSON. It only *happens* to be valid YAML, so a lenient JSON parser might be less likely to get tripped up by it at some point down the road.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed not valid JSON. It is, however, valid [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/), so the third-party [PyYAML](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML) library might help you out:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load(text)
{
    'about': 'RRDtool xport JSON output',
    'meta': {
        'start': 1401778440,
        'step': 60,
        'end': 1401778440,
        'legend': [
            'rta_MIN',
            'rta_MAX',
            'rta_AVERAGE'
        ]
    },
    'data': [
        [None, None, None],
        [None, None, None],
        [None, None, None],
        [None, None, None],
        [None, None, None],
        [None, None, None]
    ]
}
```